# Getting the HostName of a Remote iOS Device with NSNetService

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, bonjour, nsnetservice

After more than a few hours of searching, I got in what looks like a dead end. In this case, all that I am trying to do, is to get all the iOS Devices of the network with Bonjour. I did so like this

```
self.serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
[self.serviceBrowser setDelegate:self];
[self.serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_apple-mobdev2._tcp." inDomain:@"local."];
```

This works fine, though what I get is the following:

```
local. _apple-mobdev2._tcp. [MAC ADDRESS HERE]
```

I tried to resolve the connection by using the sync port (62078), since service.port returns -1.

```
for (NSNetService *service in self.services) {
    NSLog(@"%@", service);
        NSNetService *newService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:service.domain type:service.type name:service.name port:62078];
        [newService setDelegate:self];
        [newService resolveWithTimeout:30];
}
```

This in its own turn calls netServiceWillResolve: with no problem at all, but, it doesn't make it to netServiceDidResolveAddress:

But neither does this fail. netService:didNotResolve: isn't called either, I believe it is just waiting for a response to be resolved.

To support this claim, once it did make it to the method and actually [service hostName]; did return Yanniss-iPhone, but that happened at a completely random time that I had left the Mac App running for around half an hour. What could have invoked this to run? Or does anyone know of a different way to get the hostName of the remote device? The other answers do not answer my question, since I am looking for the hostName of the remote device, not of the Mac device.

Relative to that, I've found that when you kill and restart iTunes, along with iTunes Helper, the very log I mentioned below is sent again. Which is why I believe the correct log was an iTunes related event. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes search bonjour for wifi sync capability. As for the didNotResolve or resolve delay, bonjour services randomly cast itself anywhere between a few seconds to 30 minutes.

I am actually trying to connect to iOS devices too, but I could not get any response or any devices returned. :\

Comment: With iTunes WiFi Sync, I was actually able to do this! I got both the device name and the IP Address. Instead of making a new service, set the delegate of the service object of the loop to self and resolve with timeout of 30. `[service setDelegate:self]; [service resolveWithTimeout:30];` I found that iOS 9 and iOS 8 have different ports. So that's why the code above didn't work, it was just fine on my iOS 8 iPad, but not on my iOS 9 beta iPhone.